# Get a list of items from xml according to variable

Tags: c#, xml, list, xmlreader

I am looking to get a list of cities where a country equals a variable in C#

[Here is a snippet of my xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTUlX.png)

So I would like to load the cities for Afganistan into a list via a variable. Below is the code I have that shows all the values in my xml file.

```
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"Countries_Cities.xml");

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "title")
        {
            string title = reader.ReadElementString();
            Debug.WriteLine("Country Name: " + title);
        }
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "city")
        {
            string city = reader.ReadElementString();
            Debug.WriteLine("* " + city);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string[] cities = doc.Descendants("country").Where(x => (string)x.Element("title") == "Afghanistan").Descendants("city").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```